# Entity-relationship symbol

Tags: entity-relationship

[image: SQL]

I understand that this is a symbol for one to zero or many relationship, but can't get to figure out or find what this means:

[image: SQL2]

What does that "arrow" reffers to?

Comment: does such thing even exist in er!!! strange

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing a school project and while I understand all relationship symbols on our DB model diagram (one to many, one or zero to many etc etc) I can't figure out what that represents..

Comment: that is not a standard symbol.but triangle is used in case of aggregation ,still it is different

Comment: It seems to reffer to dependent relationship..solved

Comment: Well, it means that entity with triangle is dependant to existence of the other entity, but not vice-versa

Comment: oh thanx .new symbol for me:)

Comment: you want to put it as answer and accept it yourself or should I?